# How to know when FileSystem.CopyDirectory is finished?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that does this:

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(from, to, UIOption.AllDialogs);
DisplayMessage();
```

When run, the directory is copied and displays Window's in-built file copy dialog with the progress information. However, my `DisplayMessage()` runs before that dialog is closed. It doesn't run immediately after copying has begun, but the moment when the progress bar is fully complete, while the dialog hasn't yet closed. It seems like there's a slight delay (at least on my computer) between the progress bar filling up, and the dialog closing. I am assuming this can happen on other computers, too.

Since `FileSystem.CopyDirectory` does not return anything, how would I know when it is fully finished?

Comment: The actual file copying is done synchronously. The shown dialogue box is asynchronously. So your code will not go to the next line until all the files are done being processed. The window is just for shows.

Comment: Isn't FileSystem apart of VB?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey, yes, but by including `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your project, you can call it from c# code. I've found it only useful for copying full directories, which c# is missing.

Comment: I know you can include. I was just curious as more to the why. :)  But yes you are right there isn't just a straight up DirectoryCopy.

Comment: @gunr2171 Directory Copy in C# : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx   If you want it

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Yes, that is precisely the reason why I'm using it.
Still, the problem is that the window seems to lag behind after the copying operation had finished. Anyone had to deal with this before and had reached a solution?

Comment: @EWhite nice. I am actually turning that example into an extension method as we speak. :)

Comment: @GarryWong, Do you need to show the window, and does it matter if it lags behind a bit? Because of what you are calling, it does not sound like you have a lot of options. You don't have as much control over the window because of the method.

Comment: @gunr2171 Since the copy operation will likely be lengthy, I would like to display some kind of progress indication. And I'd much rather use Window's dialog than roll with something my own. I was worried about it throwing OperationCanceledException if cancel is pressed while the dialog is still up after the copy had finished, but after testing looks like it doesn't. So its only an issue of bad visual representation now, which isn't as bad. Maybe I'll just leave it as is in that case.

Comment: It is a direct call to the SHFileOperation() winapi function.  You have little to say about how it works, it got a *lot* fancier in Windows 8.  In case it matters, do not create a thread for it.  Just avoid displaying the message, the user can already tell when it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystem.CopyDirectory seems like encapsulating shell32.interop.Folder.CopyHere(...) method. So you cannot get any info about the operation since operation takes place deep inside Windows.

So I suggest to take @Cubicle.Jockey 's answer as solution.

Comment: Wow strange! while i was typing my answer, the answer i wanted to suggest disappeared! So suggestion is to write your own copy method. Check this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's ok, I saw his answer before. And I am aware of this and the other recommended method on the msdn (it just iterates through the directories in a slightly different way) to copy directories, but in both cases it would require me to implement my own progress indication, which I was trying to avoid. So I can choose between living with this little caveat of FileSystem.CopyDirectory or roll my own implementation. Thanks to everyone for the help!